# how to use custom encoding/decoding with Google Protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a python app that already has the protobuf messages defined. However, we need to use a custom wire format (I believe that's the correct term).

How do you (in python) override the base encoding functions?

I've looked in `encoder.py` and that's a maze of nested functors. So what do I need to monkey patch (or whatever) to specify my own encodings?

Thanks.

Comment: Eh, why use protobuf?

Comment: Protobuf ==== "a wire format". If you take that away: *there is nothing left*. What are you trying to do? And why?

Comment: Because the existing protocol is extremely complicated and already defined with proto files. I'm now trying to write a tester in python and would like to override the encoding. I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that custom encoding is supported by protobuf but I can't find any example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend trying to monkey-patch the encoding functions. You will almost certainly break something.

What you can do is write an independent function which encodes a protobuf in an arbitrary way via reflection. For an example of this, see the `text_format.py` module in Protobufs itself. This module encodes and decodes messages in an alternative human-readable format entirely based on the public descriptor and reflection interfaces. You can follow the same pattern to write your own encoder/decoder for any format.

Comment: I'll need to wait until Monday when I'm back at the office before I can accept this as an answer. Thank you for providing an answer however. ;)

Comment: So judging from the __author__ tag you are definitely the person to talk to! So I take it I want to override the `PrintField()` function with my own implementation? How exactly do _plug in_ a new implementation?

Comment: I'm suggesting you write a whole new module similar to `text_format.py`. You could even start by copying `text_format.py`, then editing it. There is not really a good way to "hook into" the code. People who want to use your new encoding will have to explicitly call your module.